# Router doesn't detect internet from ISP bridged router

Tags: networking, router, routing, bridge, wan

I have a brand new Asus RT-AC 1200G+ which I want to use as my main router. My ISP provider set their router to bridge mode.
So, I connected the ethernet cable from their router to my Asus wan (blue) port and started the configuration.
After entering the PPPoE details it says me that "The network cable is unplugged" and my ISP provider says that they don't detect any new router connected.

Is it possible that a brand new router has only the wan port broken? Because I can create wifi networks perfectly.
Is there any way to debug the connection or find which is the problem?

Comment: Did you confirm with your provider that you are supposed to configure the PPoE details in your router rather than them already being configured in their bridge?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that a brand new router has only the wan port broken?

Certainly, why would you think any differently? If one wheel on your car goes flat, does that mean the other three don't work? No, of course not, but you probably won't be driving anywhere until you get it fixed. :)

> Is there any way to debug the connection or find which is the problem?

Absolutely, like any other problem... Isolate and test is often the easiest thing to try, and it best to perform all testing with a WIRED interface, not WiFi.

1) Look for obvious issues... Is there a connection light on the ISP modem for the Ethernet port? Is there a connection light for the Internet port on the router? If no on either or both, try a different cable and see if the symptoms change.

2) Next, plug a PC directly into the router with a known good cable. Is there a connection light on Modem and/or PC? If no, the issue is likely with the modem, get the ISP to replace it.

3) Setup the PPP credentials in the PC and test it, does the Internet work? If not, are you getting any error messages? Verify your PPP credentials with your ISP. If everything is working, remove the credentials from the PC and reconnect the cable to the router.

4) Is there a connection light on the router for the Internet port? No, try a hard factory reset of the router and setup and test again? Still nothing? bad router... get a replacement, if yes setup the PPP connection in the setup Wizard.

5) Does the status page of the router show a connection to the Internet? If not, the router is likely bad since you checked everything else and verified it up to this point. If things look good, connect a computer to the LAN port and verify all the network settings on the PC are set to obtain information automatically.

6) Does the Internet work on the PC? If not, verify you are getting an IP address with the proper information including IP address, subnet mask, gateway, and DNS servers. Can you ping 8.8.8.8? If yes, then you are on the Internet and have a different issue (likely DNS settings).

If you are getting to this point, the next few steps could vary significantly depending on the results of your test, but in general this should get you to a point where you can isolate is it the modem, a cable, router, or a PC issue.